# Can't activate 'SharePoint Server Publishing' in 'Site Features'

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, error, master-page, publishing-site

I have 'SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure' activated in 'Site Collection Features', when I try to activate 'SharePoint Server Publishing' in 'Site Features', I get the following error:

> Sorry, something went wrong  An unexpected error has occurred. 
>   Technical Details
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
>
> Correlation ID: 1c28b79c-b0a9-9097-0000-0ba92a1a9eb4
>
> Date and Time: 9/10/2014 5:10:53 PM

I want to be able to access 'Site Master Page Settings' and is proving to be rather difficult! Any help would be grand!

Comment: Have you checked the ULS logg when you are trying to activate it? Are you sure that the feature did not get activated? Sometimes i get the same error and i succeed on my second or third time trying to activate it.

Comment: Go to your ULS logs on the server located at C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS (unless someone moved them). Each log file is generated every half hour.  Look for the file that is time stamped just after the error occurred.  Then search that file for Correlation ID: 1c28b79c-b0a9-9097-0000-0ba92a1a9eb4 at 9/10/2014 5:10:53 PM  That will give you more info about what's happening.

Comment: Thanks guys, big help. I've managed to find the error and it's the same problem as the below link.

Feature Activation: Failed to ensure feature dependencies for feature 'PublishingWeb'
[http://www.ukreddysharepoint2010.blogspot.co.uk/2014/05/error-systemargumentexception-value.html](http://www.ukreddysharepoint2010.blogspot.co.uk/2014/05/error-systemargumentexception-value.html)


His fix doesn't seem to work for me, any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$siteUrl = "http://ukreddy:3456/"
$siteCollection = Get-SPSite $siteUrl
Enable-SPFeature "PublishingSite" -Url $siteCollection.Url -force
Enable-SPFeature "PublishingWeb" -Url $siteCollection.Url -force
```

http://ukreddysharepoint2010.blogspot.co.uk/2014/05/error-systemargumentexception-value.html

Sharepoint was failing to activate the feature PublishingWeb.

Putting this command into Sharepoint Management Shell seemed to work rather than Powershell.